# Java finding the median trouble

Tags: java

Having trouble finding the median of from random values. Lets say you enter numbers like `31 62 49 76 56 54 4 7 13 59`. The two middle values would be `49 & 54`. Since its even, you would take the two values and divide by 2 to come out with the answer `51.5`. I am not getting the correct answer and I have tried several different ways.

I feel like to fully understand my program would be way to long to post up here so I created a link to the file here: [Click here to view](http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o752/Mbthirtytwo/JavaHelp_zpsc8251f00.png). If you know where I am going wrong with this please let me know.

Comment: add code here itself!!

Comment: lets see your code. paste it here

Comment: its really long... click the link to view it.

Comment: I get the value when it is odd, but when it's even It gives me random answers.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to [*Wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median):

> The median of a finite list of numbers can be found by arranging all the observations from lowest value to highest value and picking the middle one. If there is an even number of observations, then there is no single middle value; the median is then usually defined to be the mean of the two middle values.

So, if you use an array of `int`'s:

```
public static double median(int[] original) {
    int[] array = Arrays.copyOf(original, original.length);
    Arrays.sort(array);
    int central = array.length / 2;
    if (array.length % 2 == 0) {
        return (array[central - 1] + array[central]) / 2.0;
    }
    return array[central];
}
```